# Python writing in two lines instead of one

Tags: python

```
def end_aluguer(self, nickname):
    a = self.obj_aluguer(nickname)
    x = "{},{},{},{},{},{}\r".format(int(a.time), a.nickname, a.viatura, a.preco, a.decorrido(), a.update())
    y = open("historico.txt", 'a')
    y.write(x)
    y.close()
```

Hello, so i have this function and everything is working fine except when it writes in historico.txt it splits into two lines:

1607741371,tiagovski,tartaruga,0.80

,21,0.0

How can i make it to write in only one line?
Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Most likely, one of your fields has a newline in in already -- you need to strip it.

Comment: Try `a.preco.strip()`. Also, depending on where your data is coming from, maybe you want to do that to all your fields as a precaution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your data hasn't been sanitized fully yet - it hasn't been cleaned.

One of your fields, in this case, `a.preco` has newline(s) already in it -- hence, it is being written out to the file, resulting in a broken output.

Generally this:

```
a.preco.strip()
```

will suffice. But do note that this will also remove any leading and trailing whitespace (which you often want to do anyway).

Otherwise, you can specifically remove just the newline character(s) from the end using `rstrip`, like this:

```
a.preco.rstrip('\n')
```

and this will retain the leading and trailing whitespace.

Also, you may want to do the same with your other fields, depending on where your data is coming from and whether you can rely on it being in a suitable format.

Comment: Thank you! It works just how i wanted it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
def end_aluguer(self, nickname):
    a = self.obj_aluguer(nickname)
    x = "{},{},{},{},{},{}\r".format(int(a.time), a.nickname, a.viatura, a.preco, a.decorrido(), a.update())
    x = ' '.join(x.split('\n'))    # remove newline and join into one string
    y = open("historico.txt", 'a')
    y.write(x)
    y.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! But i will user the code from costaparas it's more understandable to me but this works too!